# I found a bug (or at least strange behavior) in the search

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

I found a bug (or an unwanted feature) in the search engine. Most of the queries that I found trigger this behavior have both quoted and unquoted words/phrases. Note: I have discovered that you can trigger the bug with a simple "not this tag" search, see the list at the end of this post.

When a query triggers the bug, the quoted version of the query is searched for instead. I am currently looking to see which sites this bug occurs on, but I have come to the conclusion that it does occur on non-technical sites (such as Coffee Beta), unlike was proposed here: [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/275815/158100). Additionally, I noticed that I do not need to be a member of the site to trigger this bug. (Note I am still unsure if related to user rep, which is known to change search behavior).

**This bug may affect each and every Stack Exchange site.** (Although the triggering search string may only work on certain sites.)

Second example (should work, backticked to evade search because of suggestion that the bug behavior is related to finding 0 results):
Copy this and search (and trim leading/trailing whitespace): `r`e`s`u`l`t`s` i`n`"`p`o`o`r`s`e`a`r`c`h`"`
The above example, when quotes are added around it, will give different results than if all of the quotes were removed.

My original example (may be broken now):
If I search for `bug "Bad quotes"` here on meta, I get a search for`"bug "Bad quotes""`

---

Edit: Searching other sites

Sites and working examples:

- Meta SO (here, so I'm avoiding altering search results): `-`[`f`e`a`t`u`r`e`-`r`e`q`u`e`s`t`]`
- Stack Overflow: `[c++]classes "pointers found at"`
- Coffee Beta: `[caffeine] "dark light"`
- Science Fiction and Fantasy: `[movie] "potter and harry"`
- スタック・オーバーフロー (Japanese SO): `[php] "controller default"`

---

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't reproduce this because that search now returns this question as a result...

Comment: try (but ensure there are not trailing spaces): `r`e`s`u`l`t`s` i`n` "`p`o`o`r `s`e`a`r`c`h"

Comment: Can anyone explain the downvotes?

Comment: No idea.  If I had to guess it's that other users cannot understand what exactly the problem is, or they haven't found it themselves.

Comment: I understand that my first example may be broken (if 0 results affects the appearance of the bug), but I have been very careful to keep the second one out of sight of the search engine.

Comment: see the MSE for details https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/305491/156631

Answer (score 5):

But did you notice the message on top of the search result?

> Could not find any results for bug "bad quotes"; showing 4 results for "bug "bad quotes"",

The search recognizes your search term didn't had any results so it started a second search with the terms in quotes.

If you search for [`bug "close votes"`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=bug+%22close+votes%22) you don't have that *bug*.

There is one other report over on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/275815/158100) that describes similar behavior but it has no answer.

What might be related is the fact that `bug` is also a tag. I couldn't repro this with `support` or `discussion` though. Maybe it encloses the whole string in quotes to prevent the tag detection from kicking in.

I say it is a feature... but after seeing other reports and some confirmation this probably is indeed a bug. A minor one, but still. Expect [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514) to get it fixed.

Comment: I'm not convinced. Why would this be useful? It seems more like the intention was to unquote the string (like Google does), but it failed (and added more quotes).

Comment: Well, I don't believe the on-site search was ever meant to do things like Google does

Comment: Well what is it _trying_ to do exactly with this behavior? Is it really that hard to implement unquoting?

Comment: Hmm, that note about not finding results seems new, at least, compared to when I reported the issue initially.  I should have taken a screenshot at the time.

Comment: Given what SE meta has, I highly doubt tags are to blame. I'm also unsure that it's related to code keywords. My second example has no tags out of quotes, (and minor variations trigger the bug too, such as omitting `in`).