# Rendering glitch in Stack Snippet

Tags: bug, status-declined, stack-snippets

I was trying to put all the code in this one Stack Snippet on one line. But it began to look all wrong:

[image: oh no.]

I continued, and it only got worse:

[image: OH NO!]

Note that I ran into this bug while experimenting (I did not save it, especially considering how it looked like that) with one of my posts on Meta, but I assume that it would also happen on the main site.

Chrome:

> Version 49.0.2623.112 (64-bit)

Here is the snippet, that produces the first error. If you try to edit it and scroll down some to the where the second line starts, you will get something like the first image (unless my browser is different enough):

```html
<ul><li><s><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fzi.mu">zi.mu</a></s></li><li><s><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fzi.ma">zi.ma</a></s></li><li><s><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fyhoo.it">yhoo.it</a></s></li><li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fyfrog.com">yfrog.com</a> 139 posts <strong>Defunct</strong></li><li><s><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fyep.it">yep.it</a></s></li><li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fy.ahoo.it">y.ahoo.it</a> 31 posts, all broken YQL fiddles</li><li><s><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fxurl.es">xurl.es</a></s></li><li><s><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fxrl.us">xrl.us</a></s></li><li><s><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fxrl.in">xrl.in</a></s></li><li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fwp.me">wp.me</a></li><li><s><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2furl.ie">url.ie</a></s></li><li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2furl.co.uk">url.co.uk</a></li><li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2furl.az">url.az</a></li><li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fu.nu">u.nu</a></li><li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2ftwurl.nl">twurl.nl</a></li><li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2ftwurl.cc">twurl.cc</a></li><li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2ftr.im">tr.im</a></li><li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fto.ly">to.ly</a></li><li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2ftnij.org">tnij.org</a></li><li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2ftinyurl.com">tinyurl.com</a></li><li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2ftinylink.in">tinylink.in</a></li><li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2ftiny.pl">tiny.pl</a></li><li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2ftiny.ly">tiny.ly</a></li><li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2ftiny.cc">tiny.cc</a></li><li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2ftcrn.ch">tcrn.ch</a></li>
<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fta.gd">ta.gd</a></li>
<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2ft.co">t.co</a></li>
<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2ft.cn">t.cn</a></li>
<li><s><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fsu.pr">su.pr</a></s></li>
<li><s><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fsp2.ro">sp2.ro</a></s></li>
<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fsnurl.com">snurl.com</a></li>
<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fsnipurl.com">snipurl.com</a></li>
<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fsnipr.com">snipr.com</a></li>
<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fshrt.st">shrt.st</a> 3 posts <strong>cannot reach server</strong></li>
<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fshorturl.com">shorturl.com</a></li>
<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fshort.ie">short.ie</a></li>
<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fshorl.com">shorl.com</a></li>
<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fshar.es">shar.es</a></li>
<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fsameurl.com">sameurl.com</a></li>
<li><s><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fsafe.mn">safe.mn</a></s></li>
<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fpost.ly">post.ly</a></li>
<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fping.fm">ping.fm</a></li>
<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fow.ly">ow.ly</a> 55 results</li>
<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fom.ly">om.ly</a> 1 result, cannot reach server</li>
<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fnyti.ms">nyti.ms</a></li>
<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fnsfw.in">nsfw.in</a></li>
<li><s><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fmoby.to">moby.to</a></s></li>
<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fmigre.me">migre.me</a></li>
<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2flnkd.in">lnkd.in</a></li>
<li><s><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2flinkbun.ch">linkbun.ch</a></s></li>
<li><s><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2flinkbee.com">linkbee.com</a></s></li>
<li><s><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fliip.to">liip.to</a></s></li>
<li><s><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fkrunchd.com">krunchd.com</a></s></li>
<li><s><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fkorta.nu">korta.nu</a></s></li>
<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fj.mp">j.mp</a> 381 results</li>
<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fis.gd">is.gd</a> 519 results</li>
<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fhurl.me">hurl.me</a></li>
<li><s><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fhuff.to">huff.to</a></s></li>
<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fgoo.gl">goo.gl</a> 5,257 results</li>
<li><s><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2ffwd4.me">fwd4.me</a></s></li>
<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fflic.kr">flic.kr</a> 81 results</li>
<li><s><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2ffff.to">fff.to</a></s></li>
<li><s><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fff.im">ff.im</a></s></li>
<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2ffb.me">fb.me</a></li>
<li><s><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2ffav.me">fav.me</a></s></li>
<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2feepurl.com">eepurl.com</a></li>
<li><s><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fdoiop.com">doiop.com</a></s></li>
<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fdlvr.it">dlvr.it</a></li>
<li><s><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fdisq.us">disq.us</a></s></li>
<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fdigg.com">digg.com</a></li>
<li><s><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fdigbig.com">digbig.com</a></s></li>
<li><s><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fdecenturl.com">decenturl.com</a></s></li>
<li><s><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fcutt.us">cutt.us</a></s></li>
<li><s><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fcot.ag">cot.ag</a></s></li>
<li><s><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fcli.gs">cli.gs</a></s></li>
<li><s><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fclck.ru">clck.ru</a></s></li>
<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fcl.ly">cl.ly</a></li>
<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fchilp.it">chilp.it</a></li>
<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fbudurl.com">budurl.com</a></li>
<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fbit.ly">bit.ly</a> 4,242 results</li>
<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fbinged.it">binged.it</a></li>
<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fbacn.me">bacn.me</a> 1 post, @pinged author</li>
<li><s><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2farst.ch">arst.ch</a></s></li>
<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2falturl.com">alturl.com</a></li>
<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fafx.cc">afx.cc</a> 1 post, @pinged author</li>
<li><s><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fadjix.com">adjix.com</a></s></li>
<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2fadf.ly">adf.ly</a></li>
<li><s><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2f4sq.com">4sq.com</a></s> (Note that search displays results due to <a href="http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319466">a bug I already found</a>)</li>
<li><s><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2f3.ly">3.ly</a></s></li>
<li><s><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&amp;q=url%3a%2f%2f0rz.tw">0rz.tw</a></s></li>
</ul>
```

---

Side note: Unrelated, but the Linked sidebar is picking up on a link that I have in the code, which is weird and unexpected.

Comment: can you list the steps to repo?

Comment: @gman I added the code (but have it hidden by default, because it's super long). If you edit the second snippet, you will see the bug.

Comment: No repro - Chrome 51.0.2704.29 beta (64-bit) on Xubuntu 15.10.

Comment: @Laurel I don't see this happening & also there is a **Tidy** which you may use to align/format the code.

Comment: @AniMenon If I was editing content for the main site, I would use the tidy button. In this case, I wanted to see if I could shorten the space some stuff took up, and the tidy button does not do that.

Comment: Shorten the space how? The code already turns into a scroll-able after certain lines of code?

Comment: @AniMenon I wanted to use it as an alternative to having a list of links. I only needed the code to be able to make something that emulated that.

Comment: @Laurel I didn't say your snippet was wrong, what I am saying is I don't see the same problem on my browser & also why are you trying to put up code like that? Why not *Tidy* it up?

Comment: @AniMenon This was for a Meta post, where running the SS would happen instead of just having native HTML. There was never any reason to see the code in the first place.

Comment: Right. And the SS code is view-able only to the poster/editor but the above glitch is not evident.

Comment: @AniMenon The glitch is in the SS editor, which you can see from the screen shots. I can't say if others are able to replicate it, but I really wish people wouldn't down vote this because it will limit its visibility for the devs.

Comment: I repeat, No such glitch is evident in the SS editor.

Comment: @AniMenon Clearly the issue is with particular browsers, unless you believe the OP to have fabricated the screenshot...?

Comment: No repo on Chrome Version 50.0.2661.94 m Win7. The SS editor makes visual studio look like a light-weight and blazing fast editor, though.

Comment: @Rob Didn't mean so. Its not on Chrome Version 37.0.2062.102 or IE 11.0.30 or Chrome Version 49.0.

Answer (score 3):

This happens when a line of code is so long that it needs to be split in more than 50 editor lines - in your example, the line has about 2500 characters. This is a very extreme case so I'm doing a Steve Jobs here and telling you "Just avoid coding that way" :-)